# Add or Remove PHP Variable by checking the checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am creating a filter option for the products to be filtered on my webpage. What I need to do is onclicking checkbox according to the size I need to insert the value of that specific checkbox into the php variable without reloading the page. As far as I know its not possible without using Ajax and Since I am not so familiar with Ajax I am not able to solve this query.

Php code:

```
<?php
    $importeddata="//I want the checkbox value to be imported here";
    include "connect_db.php";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bangles WHERE stat!='enable' ORDER BY product_id DESC");
    while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result)):
?>
```

Below are the checkboxes code or you may also check the **[`JSFIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/the_hardik_sisodia/uxfzz68v/1/)**:

```css
#sizetable
{
    margin-left:-10px;
    margin-top:0px;
    padding:5px;
}
#sizetable th
{
    padding:5px;
    text-align:left;
}
#sizetable label
{
    cursor:pointer;
}
.s2, .s4, .s6, .s8
{
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background: #fcfff4;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.s10
{
    width: 45px;
    height: 38px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background: #fcfff4;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.s2 label, .s4 label, .s6 label, .s8 label
{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #222222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 1px 0px white;
}
.s10 label
{
    width: 37px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #222222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 1px 0px white;
}
.s2 label:before
{
    content:'2.2';
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left:5px;
    top:0px;
    z-index: 0;
    font: 14px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.s4 label:before
{
    content:'2.4';
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left:5px;
    top:0px;
    z-index: 0;
    font: 14px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.s6 label:before
{
    content:'2.6';
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left:5px;
    top:0px;
    z-index: 0;
    font: 14px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.s8 label:before
{
    content:'2.8';
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left:5px;
    top:0px;
    z-index: 0;
    font: 14px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.s10 label:before
{
    content:'2.10';
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left:5px;
    top:0px;
    z-index: 0;
    font: 14px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.s2 label:after
{
    content:'2.2';
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    background: #27ae60;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #27ae60 0%, #145b32 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #27ae60 0%, #145b32 100%);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    opacity: 0;
    font: 14px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.s4 label:after
{
    content:'2.4';
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    background: #27ae60;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #27ae60 0%, #145b32 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #27ae60 0%, #145b32 100%);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    opacity: 0;
    font: 14px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.s6 label:after
{
    content:'2.6';
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    background: #27ae60;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #27ae60 0%, #145b32 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #27ae60 0%, #145b32 100%);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    opacity: 0;
    font: 14px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.s8 label:after
{
    content:'2.8';
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    background: #27ae60;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #27ae60 0%, #145b32 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #27ae60 0%, #145b32 100%);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    opacity: 0;
    font: 14px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.s10 label:after
{
    content:'2.10';
    width: 37px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    background: #27ae60;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #27ae60 0%, #145b32 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #27ae60 0%, #145b32 100%);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    opacity: 0;
    font: 14px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.s2 label:hover::after, .s4 label:hover::after, .s6 label:hover::after, .s8 label:hover::after, .s10 label:hover::after
{
    opacity: 0.3;
}
.s2 input[type=checkbox], .s4 input[type=checkbox], .s6 input[type=checkbox], .s8 input[type=checkbox], .s10 input[type=checkbox]
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.s2 input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after, .s4 input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after, .s6 input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after, .s8 input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after, .s10 input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after
{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" id="sizetable">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <div class="s2">
                <input type="checkbox" value="twopointtwo" id="s2" name="size" />
                <label for="s2"></label>
            </div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div class="s4">
                <input type="checkbox" value="twopointfour" id="s4" name="size" />
                <label for="s4"></label>
            </div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div class="s6">
                <input type="checkbox" value="twopointsix" id="s6" name="size" />
                <label for="s6"></label>
            </div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div class="s8">
                <input type="checkbox" value="twopointeight" id="s8" name="size" />
                <label for="s8"></label>
            </div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div class="s10">
                <input type="checkbox" value="twopointten" id="s10" name="size" />
                <label for="s10"></label>
            </div>
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: these all are selectable so you will get an array.

Comment: The only way to do it with a php variable is if you make everything use ajax. You would check the box, that would trigger an ajax call, then return the new search results. Read up on serverside vs clientside

Comment: Maybe this is some odd sizing system but in the decimal world `2.10` == `2.1`.

Comment: And I guess you want a radio group, not checkboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach a click listener for all checkboxes:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function() {
  // here grab all checked checkboxes, construct a string or JSON object and make your ajax call with the checkboxes states...
  $.ajax({
     url:...
     ...
     success: function(data) {
       // here process your results, remove previous products, insert new
     }
  });
});
```

You can also consider loading all your products (if not too much of them) and do the filtering with a client-side library like the nice [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/).

Good luck

**EDIT**

I don't have time to write down a fiddle, but [this](http://www.prashantblog.com/use-ajax-filter-mysql-results-set/) can be helpful, it's almost exactly what you want to do. Read about server-side / client-side like Hanoncs advised, read about AJAX (simply put : grabbing info from the server - PHP value from DB for instance - without reloading the page, and modify your page using those values - e.g replace unfiltered products list with the new one), Javascript, JSON, jQuery.

Comment: Can you please show me some demo how can I do it by providing some link or any fiddles, because as you said I need to grab all checkboxes & construct a string I didn't get you and the place where you wrote `// here process your results, remove previous products, insert new` you mean I need to create and add `$importeddata`this variable and its value there?

Answer (score 0):

Look the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fq2zrtwd/), you have to specify url of your php script inside, then use this in your php to fetch data from POST array

```
$importeddata = $_POST['selectedSize'];
```